# Three.Js LineBasicMaterial .shading has been removed - Can't get working

Tags: three.js

recently updated a simple three.js scene from ~ r74 to r94. Textured materials are loading correctly but LineBasicMaterial is not showing. All references to materials are giving the error ".shading has been removed. Use the boolean .flatShading instead."

I can't find where .shading is being referenced. I'm just using three.js, not referencing any other three-related js files.

I found one thread saying to check the dependencies have been updated, but I don't know how to do this and assumed everything was just in the three.js file.

Does anyone have any ideas where .shading is being set please?

Many thanks.

Comment: Open your browser's dev tools (F12). In the console, you'll see the error. Usually, it will report the file and line number along with the error. In most browsers, clicking that reference will take you to the line in the source.

Comment: Have a look in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/materials/Material.flatShading).

Comment: Thank you for the responses. My apologies for the sparseness. The error I have mentioned is in the console in dev tools in Chrome. I've searched to the point that all my google results for just "three.js materials" are purple, I've been through github conversations stretching back to 2013 but still non-the wiser. I will try and make a fiddle and update my question.Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

`LineBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights, and never has.

`LineBasicMaterial` does not utilize the `.flatShading` property.

The `.flatShading` property is only used when rendering meshes.

three.js r.94